# Restructuring a nested list

Tags: r, list, regression, linear-regression

I'm working with a nested list (ground sensors) of lists (measurement depths) of lists (data frames for each year from 2014-2018). **'SE'** indicates the sensor and its number and **'d'** represents the depth at which the sensor is placed in the soil. looks like this:

```
str(GRP3_OUT_gwFERN)

List of 9
 $ SE10:List of 3
  ..$ d20:List of 5
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8760] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8760] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8784] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8760] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ d50:List of 5
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 39.8 39.7 39.8 39.7 39.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 39.7 39.7 39.7 39.7 39.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 39 39.1 39.1 39 39 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 37.9 38 37.9 37.9 37.9 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 39.1 39 39.1 39 39 ...
  ..$ d5 :List of 5
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 41 41 40.9 41 40.9 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 42 42.1 42.1 42 42.1 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 43.3 43.4 43.4 43.3 43.3 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 42.1 42.1 42.2 42.1 42.1 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 44 44.1 44.1 44.1 44.1 ...
 $ SE11:List of 3
  ..$ d20:List of 5
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 46.6 46.5 46.4 46.4 46.4 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 46.6 46.5 46.6 46.6 46.6 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 45.1 45.1 45.1 45.1 45.1 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 40.2 40.2 40.2 40.2 40.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 49.1 49.2 49.3 49.2 49.3 ...
  ..$ d50:List of 5
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 34.1 34 34.1 34 34 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 32.8 32.8 32.8 32.7 32.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8784] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8760] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : logi [1:8760] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ d5 :List of 5
  .. ..$ 2014:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 33.8 33.8 33.8 33.8 33.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2015:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 35.7 35.7 35.7 35.7 35.7 ...
  .. ..$ 2016:'data.frame': 8784 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8784], format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8784] 31.5 31.5 31.5 31.5 31.5 ...
  .. ..$ 2017:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 28.3 28.3 28.3 28.2 28.2 ...
  .. ..$ 2018:'data.frame': 8760 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Date: Date[1:8760], format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" ...
  .. .. ..$ SWC : num [1:8760] 35.4 35.5 35.6 35.5 35.4 ..
```

As all dataframes contain NA values I want to perform linear regression to fill the gaps with NA values. I think that in order to so **I need to restructure my list in a way that I get a dataframe for year 2014, depth 20 and all the sensors that are in the list for the same year and depth**. Then in the next dataframe it's the same for year 2015, in the next one for 2016 and so on...

**Why do I wanna do this? Because in order to perform linear regression I want to create an indicator variable in a new column for (as an example) SE11 and fill the NA gaps with the values from another sensor where the correlation coefficient is highest**. **This is what it should look like for year 2014, as an example:**

```
 SE11_d20_2014_SWC SE12_d20_2014_SWC SE_44_d20_2014_SWC
             2            NA              4
             3             2              6
             NA            3             NA
             6            NA              3

 SE11_d50_2014_SWC SE12_d50_2014_SWC SE_44_d50_2014_SWC
             2            NA              4
             3             2              6
             4             5              4
            NA             3             NA
             6            NA              3


 SE11_d5_2014_SWC SE12_d5_2014_SWC SE_44_d5_2014_SWC
             2            NA              4
             3             2              6
             4             5              4
            NA             3             NA
             6            NA              3
```

I already did some research and looked for restructuring lists but unfortunately I could not find anything that would help me. Can anyone help?

**EDIT for toydata: (copy of my list and its structure)**

```
dat <- setNames(replicate(3, setNames(replicate(3, setNames(lapply(2014:2018, function(y) {
    d <- expand.grid(date=as.Date(as.character(seq(ISOdate(y, 1, 1, 0), ISOdate(y, 12, 31, 0), by="day"))), 
                     hour=1:24)
    d$swc <- rnorm(nrow(d))
    d[order(d$date), -2]
}), 2014:2018), simplify=F), c("d20", "d50", "d5")), simplify=F), c("SE104", "SE105", "SE106"))
```

Phil

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to convert the `list` to a `data.frame` and retain all the nesting information. You can then filter it to you needs.

You can do this with a `for()` loop.

I created some data to showcase it:

```r
vec_a <- c(1,2,3)
vec_b <- c(10,20,30)

l <- list(
  top1 = list(
    middle1 = list(
      a=vec_a,
      b=vec_b
    ),
    middle2 = list(
      a=vec_a,
      b=vec_b
    )
  ),
  top2 = list(
    middle1 = list(
      a=vec_a,
      b=vec_b
    ),
    middle2 = list(
      a=vec_a,
      b=vec_b
    )
  ),
  top3 = list(
    middle1 = list(
      a=vec_a,
      b=vec_b
    ),
    middle2 = list(
      a=vec_a,
      b=vec_b
    )
  )
)

str(l)
#> List of 3
#>  $ top1:List of 2
#>   ..$ middle1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:3] 10 20 30
#>   ..$ middle2:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:3] 10 20 30
#>  $ top2:List of 2
#>   ..$ middle1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:3] 10 20 30
#>   ..$ middle2:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:3] 10 20 30
#>  $ top3:List of 2
#>   ..$ middle1:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:3] 10 20 30
#>   ..$ middle2:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:3] 1 2 3
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:3] 10 20 30

library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame()

for (i in seq_along(l)){
  df <- l[[i]] %>% bind_rows(.id = "level2") %>% 
    mutate(level1 = names(l)[i])
  d <- d %>% bind_rows(df)
}

d
#>     level2 a  b level1
#> 1  middle1 1 10   top1
#> 2  middle1 2 20   top1
#> 3  middle1 3 30   top1
#> 4  middle2 1 10   top1
#> 5  middle2 2 20   top1
#> 6  middle2 3 30   top1
#> 7  middle1 1 10   top2
#> 8  middle1 2 20   top2
#> 9  middle1 3 30   top2
#> 10 middle2 1 10   top2
#> 11 middle2 2 20   top2
#> 12 middle2 3 30   top2
#> 13 middle1 1 10   top3
#> 14 middle1 2 20   top3
#> 15 middle1 3 30   top3
#> 16 middle2 1 10   top3
#> 17 middle2 2 20   top3
#> 18 middle2 3 30   top3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This would mean that I first have to define all the vectors that I want to put into the dataframe, right? (Like you did with `vec_a <-` and `vec_b <-`)
The problem with that is that I have 146 sensors in total, so this might be an option for a list that only contains 9 sensors but it would take ages to do so for the total amount of sensors.

Comment: I have just made `vec_a` and `vec_b` to create the example list. In the actual code, these two vectors are not named. If you post part of your data with `dput(data)` then it is possible to give you an exact answer to your specific data.

Comment: Edited the post so you have some toy data. I used `dput()` for two sensors of the same depth and the same year so you have two vectors in total.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that this is not gonna help you. Edited again, now you have the list with the appropriate structure.